# gmdate 12 hours off

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get the GMT to send with an API request however my time is off from the actual GMT.

Right now the GMT is 6:40 PM Friday, November 20, 2020.

However when I run

```
gmdate("Y-m-d\Th:i:s\Z");
```

I get 2020-11-20T06:47:07Z. Which is 6AM instead of PM.

How do I get the correct GMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `h` to `H` to get a 24 hour hour. The small `h` gives you the hour in 12 hour format.

```
gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```